Reachable States in a Product of Transition Systems
I am trying to deepen my understanding of transition systems and synchronization schemes and would appreciate some insights.
Consider the following scenario:
We have three transition systems A1, A2, and A3.
A1 and A2 each have 2 states. A3 has 3 states. There is a synchronization scheme S applied to these systems.
I am curious about the number of states reachable from the initial state in the free product A1×A2×A3. How can I determine the exact number of states reachable from the initial state when considering the synchronization scheme S?
Any detailed explanation or examples to help me understand the reachability of states in this context would be greatly appreciated.

What's a synchronization scheme? I can't seem to find any relevant answer on google.

You can use the same method for finding the reachable states in any transition system.  Construct the transition graph for the system $A1 \times A2 \times A3$ (constructed using the product construction, taking into account $S$).  Do depth-first search in this graph to find all reachable states.  Count the number of states that were reached by DFS.
